# Missing lines when iterating over a column in numpy

Tags: list

I am trying to pass a `csv` fie containing `x`, `y`, `z` coordinates. I am using Python's `NumPy` package to do this as shown in the code below:

```
enter code here#
!/usr/bin/python

from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

pdb_file=open('/home/josh/Documents/cordinates_all.csv')
x_new_file=open('/home/josh/Documents/x_new_cordinates.txt','w+')
y_new_file=open('/home/josh/Documents/y_new_cordinates.txt','w+')
z_new_file=open('/home/josh/Documents/z_new_cordinates.txt','w+')
test=open('/home/josh/Documents/test.txt','w+')

cordinates=np.genfromtxt(pdb_file,delimiter=",")



###slicing each "column" on the basis of X ,Y and Z cordinates
x=cordinates[:,][:,0]  
y=cordinates[:,][:,1]
z=cordinates[:,][:,2]


x_max=max(x)
x_min=min(x)

cx=(x_max-x_min)/2.0

y_max=max(y)
y_min=min(y)

cy=(y_max-y_min)/2.0

z_max=max(z)
z_min=min(z)

cz=(z_max-z_min)/2.0

###list of centre cordinates
cxyz=[cx,cy,cz]


####print(len(x),len(y),len(z))
#####print(np.isnan().any()) #check for missing values in the array
for count,elem in enumerate(y):
  print(count ,file=test) 
  print (((x[count])*1.05),file=x_new_file)
```

The `print(count,file=test)` line is just to check whether I got a value of 83366 in the count variable (which i did).

The coordinate file has 83367 lines. Using `len()` I am able to verify that all `x` ,`y` and `z` columns have the same number of lines. In addition, using `isnan().any()` i can verify that they do not have any `NaN` or missing values.

Nevertheless, when i loop over each column to perform arithmetic on each value, each column gets a different number of elements and I do not know why.

I am new to the `NumPy` package so maybe it is something i am doing wrong?

Please advise.

**Note:** I am using Python 2.7 under the enthought `canopy` environment in `Ubuntu` 15.04.

Answer (score 0):

Using flush() on the file object solves the problem